# grails question (sample 1 of Grails To Action book) problem with Controller and Service

Tags: grails, service, controller, dns

I'm doing Grails To Action sample for chapter one. Every was just fine until I started to work with Services. When I run the app I have the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: quoteService for class: qotd.QuoteController

at qotd.QuoteController$_closure3.doCall(QuoteController.groovy:14)

at qotd.QuoteController$_closure3.doCall(QuoteController.groovy)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here is my groovie QuoteService class, which has an error within the definition of  GetStaticQuote (ERROR: Groovy:unable to resolve class Quote)

```
 package qotd

    class QuoteService {

 boolean transactional = false

 def getRandomQuote() {
  def allQuotes = Quote.list()
  def randomQuote = null
  if (allQuotes.size() > 0) {
   def randomIdx = new Random().nextInt(allQuotes.size())
   randomQuote = allQuotes[randomIdx]
  } else {
   randomQuote = getStaticQuote()
  }
  return randomQuote
 }

 def getStaticQuote() {
  return new Quote(author: "Anonymous",content: "Real Programmers Don't eat quiche")
 }
     }
```

**Eclipse show me an error flag on the definition of getStaticQuote:**

```
ERROR: Groovy:unable to resolve class Quote
```

**Any Clues?**

Controller groovie class

```
package qotd

class QuoteController {

   def index = {
     redirect(action: random)
   }

   def home = {
     render "<h1>Real Programmers do not each quiche!</h1>" 
   }

  def random = {
     def randomQuote = quoteService.getRandomQuote()
     [ quote : randomQuote ]
   }

  def ajaxRandom = {
     def randomQuote = quoteService.getRandomQuote()
     render "<q>${randomQuote.content}</q>" +
     "<p>${randomQuote.author}</p>"
   }
}
```

Quote Class:

```
package qotd

class Quote {
   String content
   String author
   Date created = new Date()

   static constraints = {
     author(blank:false)
     content(maxSize:1000, blank:false) 
    }
}
```

I'm doing the samples using STS. Any advice?

Regards,

Francisco

Answer (score 3):

do

`def quoteService`

at the top of your controller and it will be injected into the controller automatically

Comment: Thanks, you're right!

But Why I have the following error, on the definition of getStaticQuote method on QuoteService Class?:

 ERROR: Groovy:unable to resolve class Quote on my QuoteService class?

Comment: Perhaps your grails-app/domain directory is not defined as a source folder. I definitely recommend using SpringSource Tool Suite with the Grails support rather than pure Eclipse. It's free and the Grails support is pretty solid and getting better all the time.

Comment: Peter's advice seems good.  All your stuff is in the same package, so Quote should be visible in the service.  Make sure your directory structure conforms to the grails convention -- remember, Grails is 'convention over configuration', and as Peter suggested, make sure in Eclipse that the folder that contains all of your controllers/services/domain classes are source folders.

Answer (score 0):

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: quoteService for class: qotd.QuoteController

I dont code in grails but it appears as though you need to declare quoteService somewhere in the controller.

Comment: It seems that in Grails you don't have to.

Comment: In Grails, you don't have to *instantiate* the service class, but you do have to *declare* it (as hvgotcodes has answered). Grails (or Spring more specifically) then auto-wires the service into the controller (or whereever you need it).

Comment: Woot4Moo where right, I should declare quoteService at the top of the Controller class:

def quoteService

Answer (score 0):

I did

> def quoteService = new QuoteService()

and it solved my problem

Comment: I think you should not do the "new QuoteService()" -- just "def quoteService". Otherwise you are loosing dependency injection.

Comment: At that time (in August 2011), I actually didn't know about the dependency injection.